# Map primary key to composite key in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 tables namely user & user_session.

User table has user_id as a primary key which is referrers to user_session table.

Plus user_session has composite key including session_intime and user_id.

I have designed my entity in JPA. Now I want to map these two entities. I have tried to map these two tables. But my application build failed. Can you please help me out?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Email
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String fname;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserSession userSession;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_session")
public class UserSession{
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserSessionPK userSessionPK;

    @Column(name = "remote_ip")
    private String remoteIp;
}

@Embeddable
public class UserSessionPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_in")
    private Date timeIn;
}
```

I want to map user_id of User table to user_id of UserSessionPK. I am new to JPA, so I don't know how to map with embeddable class.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: com.recruitment.model.login.UserSession.userSessionPK.userId in mappedBy of com.recruitment.model.login.User.userSession

Comment: I have just added the mapping in User table also, which giving me this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the mappedBy attribute. This attribute is used when you have bidirectional relationship to indicate which side of the relationship is the owner.

But you will need to set the Foreign Key aka JoinColumn

```
@JoinColumn("user_id")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private UserSession userSession;
```

Comment: I have tried what you have said. Application runs successfully but now it is throwing error as Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.user_session_time_in' in 'field list'

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I updated my answer. You will need @JoinColumn

Comment: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: userSession.id of: com.recruitment.model.login.User

Comment: Hmm. The issue is that the relationship User -> UserSession is not OneToOne it's OneToMany. Right?

Comment: Yes. One user can log in multiple time with multiple sessions.

Comment: So I have changed my mapping as OneToMany and it gives me: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a OneToMany, ManyToMany or CollectionOfElements: com.recruitment.model.login.User.userSession

Comment: Thanks for your help. OneToMany solved my problem. I have updated my code.

Comment: Great I'm happy to help. I will updated the answer accordingly